# Visual studio tool unity unistall disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2012, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-extensions

I installed a Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 Unity tool extension recently and now it is making my unity editor act very annoy. Lose links, intellisense continual crash, … I would like to uninstall this tool.

I Installed: 
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7ab11d2a-f413-4ed6-b3de-ff1d05157714
And accidentally installed the 2013 version as well (Can't post link)

Tried this Visual Studios 2012: Tools > Extension and Updates
[(Image of error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVJQ6.png)

Cant find other forums online, how do I uninstall it?

Comment: Tried uninstalling whole visual studio..? and/or this, https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller

Comment: Using an old student license. A little afraid itll be rejected. I'll try that in two weeks when my project isnt at a risky stage. I appreciate the link